# Running MPI job on non-standard ssh port

Tags: ssh, mpi

I'm setting up to run some parallel jobs using MPICH 3.2 and I tried to test the configuration (3 Nodes, named Ruby, Sapphire and Onyx (Master)) using the example program *cpi* provided with the installation. When I tried to run the job I the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host Ruby_Slave port 22: No route to host
Host key verification failed.
```

Ruby is running ssh on a non-standard ssh port, which I think might be the problem. Is there any way to specify the port used for ssh in MPI?

Edit1:

```
Host Sapphire
    HostName 10.42.43.11
    Port 22
    PasswordAuthentication no
    EnableSSHKeysign yes
    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Comment: There is no such thing as Open MPI 3.2. The project has just released version 2.0.0. Your implementation is probably MPICH.

Comment: My bad, I am running MPICH. I'll edit the question appropriately.

Comment: That's an important information since both implementations have sufficiently different formats of the machine files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't specify the port used for SSH in MPI.

You can however tell SSH which port to use, on a machine by machine basis, in `.ssh/config`. The user configuration file is (usually) located in `~/.ssh/config` and the system-wide configuration file is located in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Here's an example configuration:

```
Host 192.168.0.101
Port 5101
Host 192.168.0.102
Port 5102
```

Also take a look at `man ssh_config`.

Comment: Would this be equivalent to settings in /etc/ssh/ssh_config? I have specified the particular ports to be used there. E.g: 

    Host Ruby
    HostName 10.1.10.128
    Port 1246
    PasswordAuthentication no
    RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    EnableSSHKeysign yes

Comment: @Boss1295 I think that you have `Host` and `HostName` wrong. I believe the IP address should follow `Host` and `Ruby` should follow `HostName`.

Comment: I just added what was in the global ssh_config file to the local ssh_config file, it looks like there are multiple aliases for the machines in the hosts file and it was not recognizing them. The error I am getting is changed and is consistent with more ssh problems in the same vein. I'll propagate these changes across the machines and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, just saw your second comment, that seeming works fine for me ssh'ing between machines outside of MPI. I'll edit my question with the file properly formatted.

Comment: @Boss1295 Your config file is correct, I got it backwards.

Comment: Alright, I'm getting some more errors pertaining to firewalls. I'll look into those, but this answers my original question. If I have any more I'll let you know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Boss1295 No problem at all